# Parsing and adding multiple redundant tree nodes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a tree, where nodes contain references to two parent nodes; due to the way things work, they can, at some point, point to the same nodes.

```
Example:

Parent1: Node234234 -> Node233645 -> Node2323429 -> Node2939230
Parent2: Node112938 -> Node2323429 -> Node2939230
```

If I am simply trying to parse each node once, and only once, no matter how many times it may appear, how would you do this?

I've thought about using List.Contains, and then halting if it's true, but it seems kind of messy; I've thought about using a HashTable (where I just let add the nodes), but I think that could be widely inefficient on larger trees. What would you consider to be an efficient, fast solution?

Comment: try to use linklist to save this two list you wrote, and find the intersect point. then you can parse each node once.

Comment: @user978122 after reading your question again I realized I don't really know what you want. Do you have the tree in memory already, i.e. in a tree data structure or are you reading input in the exemplified form and creating a new tree? If it is the second option, then only the bloom filter (in my answer) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

** EDIT: **
*After reading your question again I have good reason to believe that I misinterpreted it. It seems to me you are actually parsing text input and creating a tree from it. If so, please ignore option no. 2.*

I can think of two ways right now that could be worh it:
**1.** Using a *bloom filter*. It is definitely worth it in terms of space if your trees are large, and it may fit your needs if the nodes don't repeat too often, and if you can tolerate some nodes not being parsed at all. Some nodes may not be parsed because this structure may return false positives for the *belongs to* operator (it is a probabilistic data structure in that sense). Check its page on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) fore more info.

**2.** Creating trees of a class that wraps your current node class and adds a boolean that is set to true once the node is visited. Something such as:

```
class NodeAndVisitationInfo {
    public bool Visited;
    public NodeType Node;

    public NodeAndVisitationInfo() {
        Visited = false;
    }
}
```

This second solution may not be ideal if you need to do this operation more than once, since in that case you should set `Visited` to `false` for all nodes in both trees before running your visiting algorithm again. Also, do note that this algorithm is completely *not thread safe*.

---

Above all, do not go for a simple `List.Contains` call for every new parsed node, this will be O(n^2) for the worst-case scenario. If you are storing your nodes in a search structure, prefer one whose both amortized insertion and search complexities are better. An ordered list or even a hashset may be better for that matter.